# Python - QT. Mainwindow closed unwanted on a button click. Prossed Finished with exit code 1 but no error

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qwidget

Plase be gentle with my english grammar. 
This is my first question on Stack Overflow so any critic or tips are welcomed.

I've got the following Problem. 
In my test/learn programm I should have written a simple and functional "BMI-calculator". 
When you run the code, the Mainwindow pops up and you can type youre parameters. But when you press the button, to call a function that should calculate the bmi and write it on the label "result" it directly closed.

Here is the Code:

```
import sys
from qtpy import QtWidgets
from gui.mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow

app= QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

class Mainwindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent= None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle("BMI Rechner")

        self.gui=Ui_MainWindow()
        self.gui.setupUi(self)
        self.gui.calculate.clicked.connect(self.calculate_bmi)

    def calculate_bmi(self):
        bmi=self.gui.weight.value()/(self.gui.height.value().__pow__(2))
        self.gui.result.setText(str(bmi))

window = Mainwindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I hope this is enough info and not a dumb question.
Thanks!

Comment: what is `weight` and `height`?

Comment: show your gui.py